# How to fix “Unable to boot device” error message in Xcode 9?

Tags: xcode, simulator, boot, ios11, xcode9

I am consistently getting `Unable to determine simulator device to boot` error after deleting the `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices` directory.

Tried restarting xcode, clean build but nothing works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the easiest and straightforward solution. Happy to share with the community!

**Steps -**

- `gem install snapshot` - Skip this step if you already have snapshot installed.
- `fastlane snapshot reset_simulators`

**No need to try following steps -**

- remove and add simulator using `Manage devices`
- restart mac
- try to open simulator from `Xcode -> Open Developer Tool`
- sudo commands etc.

These solutions sometimes work but often they don't. So next time just try `fastlane snapshot reset_simulators`

Answer (score 9):

Just run  `xcrun simctl erase all` in Terminal. It helped me.

Answer (score -1):

I had another user logged in. Logging out of the user fixed the problem. While it is not unusual for my laptop to have multiple users logged in, the difference was that this is the first time I had the TV app running on the other user.